# I don't have Powerpoint object library on the list of available references, even though I have installed

Tags: vba, excel, ole

I try to write an Excel VBA program that automatically creates a Powerpoint presentation. As far as I know, at first I should go to tools -> references and on the list of available references find and switch on the reference to the Powerpoint object library. However, on the list of available references I don't have the Powerpoint object library. What can I do to have it available? I have Powerpoint install and it works without problems.

Yes, I know I can use Powerpoint from Excel VBA macro without referencing to this object library (I can use late binding), but I would like to avoid that.

Edit:
Hm... just several minutes after posting this question I can see I have this reference on the list of available references. But I am quite sure that before I didn't have it. Is it possible that it became available now because just one minute ago I started PowerPoint?

Answer (score 0):

The PowerPoint library file is msppt.olb.

If, for whatever reason it wasn't shown in this list, you could add it by running the regsvr32 command to register this particular file, or re-install PowerPoint - both should do the trick. Registering a COM file in this way puts a whole bunch of additions into the registry to let Windows know where the file is, how it can be accessed & what it's dependencies are.

In this case (i) I'm glad to hear you've already fixed the problem and (ii) sorry but it's unlikely - I'm guessing you just didn't spot it in the list the first time around (which is pretty easily done).